self created X.509Certificate missing ca hierarchy
The X.509 certificate created through self programming cannot display the certificate hierarchy properly in the certificate viewer of Chrome browser. Is there any missing information?
1.in browser

2.double click open the certificate

3.The certificate materials are here
4.if i remove 'TestCASecondLevel' from certmgr,it becomes not security,and ca not display


If you trusted the TestCASecondLevel in your browser, i.e. used it as a trust anchor then it doesn't need to keep looking for the root... Remember, the process tries to build a trust path to a trust anchor, and usually this is a root certificate. But it doesn't need to be.

I added a screenshot in the fourth point, but deleting it is still incorrect. Or is it that the certificate issued by oneself will never display the certificate path correctly.

Yes, that means you have to add the root cert to the trust store, and that you have to include the intermediate certificate to the chain that will be send by the server (i.e. together with the leaf certificate and the private key). Presuming that the second CA cert is not self signed of course, in that case it is the root certificate.
